# Loading page in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, loading

I have the following problem. I want to generate a little loading pop up that notifies the user that the computer is working. However, when I run the following code, it seems that stuff_that_takes_a_while() is executed immediatly and the pop up comes after ( the pop up does come because it shows when I delete the lp.close_() ). I thought that Python as a scripting language would execute the instructions in order. Any theory why this doesn't work? Any help is GREATLY appreciated in advance.

```
from Tkinter import *

def stuff_that_takes_a_while():
    #stuff
    pass

class LoadPage():
    def show_(self):
        self.popup.geometry("500x100") #Width x Height
        label = Label(self.popup, text=self.text, font="Arial 11")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        self.popup.transient(master) #set to be on top of the main window
        self.popup.grab_set() #hijack all commands from the master (clicks on the main window are ignored)
    def close_(self):
        self.popup.destroy()
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.popup = Toplevel(master)
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    master = Tk()
    lp = LoadPage("Loading...")
    lp.show_()
    stuff_that_takes_a_while()
    lp.close_()
    mainloop()
```

Comment: Because the tkinter mainloop is not yet executed to handle the LoadPage.  Add `lp.update()` after `lp.show_()` to perform the update.

Comment: Python is a scripting language that executes in order but Tkinter has its own event loop scheduler etc.

Comment: @acw1668 Sorry I forgot to include it in my question but mainloop() is in my original code.

Comment: What I mean is that `mainloop()` is not yet executed between `lp.show_()` and `stuff_that_takes_a_while()` so the `LoadPage` will not be shown.  Add `master.update()` after `lp.show_()`.

Comment: @acw1668 This does work. Thank you very much my friend!

Answer (score 0):

@acw1668 found the solution:

Since mainloop() is not yet executed between lp.show_() and stuff_that_takes_a_while(), the LoadPage will not be shown. Add master.update() after lp.show_().

```
from Tkinter import *

def stuff_that_takes_a_while():
    #stuff
    pass

class LoadPage():
    def show_(self):
        self.popup.geometry("500x100") #Width x Height
        label = Label(self.popup, text=self.text, font="Arial 11")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        self.popup.transient(master) #set to be on top of the main window
        self.popup.grab_set() #hijack all commands from the master (clicks on the main window are ignored)
    def close_(self):
         self.popup.destroy()
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.popup = Toplevel(master)
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    master = Tk()
    lp = LoadPage("Loading...")
    lp.show_()
    master.update()
    stuff_that_takes_a_while()
    lp.close_()
    mainloop()
```